# Counting words that start with Capital Letters C++ [Help]

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hey everyone I'm a newbie to C++ and could use some help.
I'm trying to code a program which counts only the words that start with Capital Letters.

```
int countLegalWords(char str[])

int counter = 0; // counts the legal words

for (int i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; i++)
{
    if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
    {
        if (str[i + 1] >= 'a' && str[i + 1] <= 'z')
        {
            counter++;
        }
        else if (str[i] == ' ')
            i++;
    }
}

return counter;
```

**Example**:

**Input:**

**I** liKE **I**ce **C**ream **H**

**Output:**

4 words with capital letters at the beginning of the word.

Comment: So what is the problem with this code other than the missing `{` and `}`

Comment: I don't like `MAXSIZE`. How do you know `str[]` contains that many characters?

Comment: Whatever source you're using to learn C++ I would argue it's not doing a very good job. First of all you should almost always use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for strings. Secondly your checks for upper or lower case letters is flawed, you should be using [`std::isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper) and [`std::islower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/islower) instead.

Comment: `str[i + 1]` could be a bug. And `if (str[i] == ' ')` will never be true because you know that `str[i]` is between 'A' and 'Z' since it entered the above block of the first if ()

Comment: There's also some logical problems with your code. Use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring your variables and their values to help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: The code works for me but the issue is that the output shows only 3 capital letters not 4.  It won't count the first word and also I think it counts the second one (liKE)

Comment: @Nitzan To add what was stated, the reason why you should use `std::isupper` and `std::islower` is that the system knows what is an upper and lower case character.   Your code is flawed in two ways: 1) It only works for systems where the letters are contiguous in the collating sequence and 2) You may miss capitalized words if the language is not English.

Comment: @Nitzan *The code works for me* -- If it worked for you, then you shouldn't have an issue.   But clearly it isn't working.  Since you're new, code that "doesn't work" means that your code is faulty, not that the code works and something is wrong with the "system".  You have to now debug the code to see where your mistake is.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Okay I changed to isUpper and IsLower but still for some reason when I type "HeY" it counts it as a word. I only want it to be counted if it's "H" or "Hey".

Comment: You still need to debug your code, regardless of what you changed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah I debugged the code. The issue is that it also counts capital letters after the first letter. I'm not sure how I can fix it though.

Comment: Your goal is easily reached by using [std::istringstream](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae13b1f92a3fe9fe).  All that code does at the link is to treat the character string as if it was typed in as input, one word at a time.  Is that what you are looking for as a solution?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for helping. I actually wanted to use strcmp if possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code

1. In C++, `std::string` is used for strings. Things like ´char*´ or ´char[]´ are not used in C++ They are used in C. But C and C++ are 2 different languages
2. You use a C-Style array (`char str[]`). In C++, C-Style arrays are not used
3. There is a magic constant MAXSIZE, which has nothing to do with the length of the string. If MAXSIZE is 100 but the your string is smaller, then you compare out of bounds values in the for loop. This is a severe bug.
4. You need to understand that C-style strings are 0-terminated. The last charcter is a '\0'. You must not operate past the terminating 0.
5. Your logic in detecting words and word begin is wrong. You check **any** character for uppercase and then the next for lowercase. But this can happen also within a word. See your sentence with "liKe" in it.
6. You do not want to switch to C++. You have written in the comment that you want to use `strcmp` and such, which is a C-function
7. If you would write comments and use meaningful variable names, then you would find all errors by yourself.

OK, that were the problems. Now a possible solution, using your programming style.

```
#include <iostream>

int countLegalWords(char myString[]) {

    // Here we will store the number of words which start with a capital letter
    int countOfLegalWords = 0; 

    // We will iterate over the complete string and check all characters
    unsigned int indexInString = 0;

    // Check all characters of the string until we hit the terminating 0
    while (myString[indexInString] != '\0') {

        // Search for the begin of a word. This is the first non-space character
        while (myString[indexInString] == ' ')
            ++indexInString;

        // OK, Now we found the begin of a word. Check, if the first character is upper case
        if ((myString[indexInString] >= 'A') and (myString[indexInString] <= 'Z')) {

            // Yes, uppercase, count up
            ++countOfLegalWords;
        }
        // Now search for the end of the word or for the end of the complete string
        while ((myString[indexInString] != '\0') and (myString[indexInString] != ' '))
            ++indexInString;

    }
    // And return the count of legal words to ther calling program
    return countOfLegalWords;
}

int main() {
    char myString[] = "I liKE Ice Cream H";
    std::cout << "\nCount of legal words: " << countLegalWords(myString) << '\n';
}
```

---

in C++ all this would be done with a one liner:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>

// Regex for a word starting with a capital letter
const std::regex re{ R"(\b[A-Z]\w*)" };

// Main program
int main() {
    std::string myString{ "I liKE Ice Cream H" };
    std::cout << "\nCount of legal words: " << std::distance(std::sregex_token_iterator(myString.begin(), myString.end(),re), {}) << '\n';
}
```